# Facebook graph api - access a public friends list of a user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was trying to understand permissions around friends list using graph api explorer.

If there is a user whose friends list is public and the user is not in my friends list nor do I have any mutual friends with that person - i can still see friends of that person on Facebook which tells me that their friends list is public. But when I use graph api explorer to do the same for that user I see the following exception:

```
{
    "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation", 
    "type": "FacebookApiException", 
    "code": 100
    }
}
```

Does someone know why that is?

Also, another related question is - even if I can see my friend's friends on Facebook, I cant see that via graph api explorer because for graph api to show it my friends should have made their friends list public, is that correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API only allows you to see friends of the authenticated user. This is correct way as it's saying

> I (the authenticated user) am granting you (the application) access to see my friends

So friends of friends, non-mutual and so on are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks. But I could see friends list of a friend, but not another friend. Since I was directly using the explorer tool, my guess is the difference could be that the latter friend might have the platform turned off, right? As for accessing friends of a totally unrelated user, I cannot do that even if their friends list is public and the platform is turned on?